# how to identify wather execution of updatequery made changes or not in oracle database

Tags: jdbc

I am using oracle as backhand and jsp servlet as frunthand I am executing update query and I want to identify whether update query has made updation in database or not. i am using executeUpdate() it is executing but it results 0 when update query fails to execute and 1 when execution is done but it does not identify whether data is updated or not

Answer (score 0):

[executeUpdate](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) will return the number of modified rows on your update sentence. So if you are getting 0, it does not mean it failed to execute but no rows were modified upon execution. And if you are getting 1, you've managed to update **one** row.

Usually, if update sentence failed, you will get a SQLException thrown by the JDBC driver.

Comment: i got the point but how can i identify wather updation has made or not?

Comment: Still having problem the actual problem is my update query change only on row in my database but if i execute first time it results 1 and if i execute it same query 2nd time still it answers 1 while record is not updated, and if i execute same moer still it shows 1 as answer